# JFrame stops receiving mouse events

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, mouse-listeners

I have a JFrame, which represents the GUI for my Java application.
I have a custom button, derived from JComponent and created and placed on this JFrame. On pressing this button a modal dialog appears.

The problem is, that after modal dialog appears, the JFrame stops receiving mouse events from mouse. I opened Spy++ and found out that MouseEvents from Windows are passed to the JFrame. So they are switched off somewhere in Java.

I need to receive button events for one thing - when mouse enters my custom button area, button changes color. And I need to know when the mouse exits the button area, to change the button to it's original color. The same problem is with standard JButton - it remains hovered after modal dialog appears.

Of course I can track the opening of modal dialog myself, and make my button unhovered, but just curious, if there is standard solution.

You see, that the button on the JFrame remains hovered as the dialog appears.

```
package quixote.sscce;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FrameTop extends JFrame implements MouseListener, ActionListener {
    private JButton button;


    public FrameTop() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(200, 200);
        setLocation(100, 100);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        button = new JButton("Click me");
        add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, "dialog");
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.setLocation(150, 150);
        dialog.setSize(100, 100);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }


    private int aaa = 0;
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("XXX " + aaa);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("XXX " + aaa);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("XXX " + aaa);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("XXX " + aaa);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("XXX " + aaa);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final FrameTop top = new FrameTop();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                top.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? It would be much much easier to find out what the problem is.

Comment: It works fine here.  What are the [details of the JRE](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.vendor%2Cjava.version&format=TSV) in which it fails?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have forgot set `opaque` ie. `setOpaque(true)`.

This will allow you to change background colour of frame and for button `button.setOpaque(true)`.

Try it, it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use non modal dialog, and call dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
hope this helps